# Затемнение текста в конце блока, если он не влезает CSS

Tags: html, css

Я ищу затемнение текса, который не влезает в блок. Пример на картинке

[image: ФИО не влезает и мы его расстворяем]

Вся проблема в том что мне необходимо использовать такой же эффект на цветном фоне и уже градиентом или png-шкой не обойтись, как минимум из-за того что сатй адаптивный и положение цветов под этим тестом может меняться при изменении экрана.

Кто нибудь знает решение данной проблемы? Или какой-то другой эффект?

Answer (score 5):

**Вариант с SVG.** Поддержка браузерами - [97.6%](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html5)

Можно ловить события мыши, как-будто там настоящий текст:

```css
body{
background:url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/any")
}

svg text:hover{
   text-decoration:underline
}
```

```html
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   id="svg4"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 65.278961 7.5305481"
   width="65.278961mm"
   height="7.5305481mm">
  <defs
     id="defs8">
    <linearGradient
       id="linearGradient3606">
      <stop
         id="stop3602"
         offset="0"
         style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1;" />
      <stop
         id="stop3604"
         offset="1"
         style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:0;" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       y2="2.8314598"
       x2="63.9076"
       y1="2.4555328"
       x1="48.118664"
       id="linearGradient3608"
       xlink:href="#linearGradient3606" />
  </defs>

  <text
     id="text3600"
     y="5.9182434"
     x="-0.18603516"
     style="font-size:8px;font-family:sans-serif; fill:url(#linearGradient3608);"
     xml:space="preserve">Дмитрий Сергеев</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

Через прозрачный текст , а градиент на фон и свойство background-clip: text.

```css
.grad {
  width: 120px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: red;
  /* Для старых браузеров */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 0%, red 30%, red 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #33ff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="grad">Фамилия Имя</div>
```

Comment: Это же только для webkit'ов?

Comment: нет , не только

Comment: Это не модераторы. Вариант с `-webkit` дописал я - _дописал,_ не заменил. Если браузер поддерживает хотя бы один из них, то он отобразит корректно. Но вот без `-webkit` в актуальном хроме не работает: значение без префикса зачёркнуто как невалидное https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXbXK.png, а если убрать с префиксом, то будет просто фон: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zMJP.png. В других браузерах я не проверял, но, насколько я помню, этот способ работал только для вебкитов. На [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) третья сноска про text - официально такого значения нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, согласен, тут на [en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) есть применение с text , но  IE и EDGE его не поддерживают.

Comment: О, в стандарт включили. И FF подтянулась. Но IE+ как всегда. Кстати, стоит в `@supports` обернуть, а то фоллбек с прозрачным шрифтом по красному бекграунду - это как-то не очень.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с `mask-image`. Пока что это более теоретический вариант, поскольку накладывание масок еще не поддерживается без префиксов, в Фаерфоксе пока что возможно накладывание исключительно SVG-масок, но перспектива радует и это свойство уже CR.

```css
.text {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 60%, transparent 80%);
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 60%, transparent 80%);
}
```

```html
<div class=text>
  lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```